# Mysql: Update all columns of table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables a_table and b_table and are initialised as:

```
create table a_table(
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
reference varchar(255),
colour varchar(255),
size varchar(255),
unique (reference)
);

insert into a_table (reference, colour, size) values
('ref1', 'red', 'big'),
('ref2', 'blue', 'small'),
('ref3', 'green', 'mini');
```

```
create table b_table(
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
reference varchar(255),
colour varchar(255),
size varchar(255),
unique (reference)
);

insert into b_table (reference, colour, size) values
('ref1', 'orange', 'tiny'),
('ref2', 'orange', 'tiny'),
('ref3', 'orange', 'tiny'),
('ref4', 'pink', 'large'),
('ref5', 'yellow', 'huge'),
('ref6', 'purple', 'small');
```

I want to update a_table with the information from b_table, and can do so with the command

```
update a_table a, b_table b
set a.colour = b.colour,
a.size = b.size
where
a.reference = b.reference
```

**What I would like to know is if there is a simpler way to list all the columns to update? so doing away with**

```
a.colour = b.colour,
a.size = b.size
```

Seems ok here as there are just two columns, but if there were 100s of columns this could get tedious.
I want to avoid using

```
replace into a_table select * from b_table
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf179cbbfb090e78acf542c6ddeec0f5 to follow along the example above

One solution could be to create an array containing the column names, and then looping through the array to create

```
a.colour = b.colour,
a.size = b.size
```

Would anyone be able to show how this could be done in Mysql?

Comment: The reason I wish to avoid using replace is because this implicitly deletes the row, and the tables I am interested in have foreign keys to other table, meaning I can not use the replace command

Comment: if you have to do it once and tehre are 20 or so columns, write the update manually, else write a stired procedure and lets do the system do it for you.

Comment: Your query is logically incorrect. `b.reference` is NOT defined as UNIQUE so random row from all rows with the same `b.reference` value will be used for both UPDATE and REPLACE and INSERT .. ODKU. You must solve this problem first.

Comment: @Akina I have amended the example to take in to consideration your comment

Comment: If there are hundreds of columns it might be time to rethink your schema design

Comment: *I have amended the example to take in to consideration your comment* I do not see. Look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6226fb75456311f57f6dc3b4ac766939)...

Comment: See also `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`

Comment: @Rick James as I understand, for this query I still need to list out every single column?

Comment: The task of listing all the columns is a one-time task.  The query will run thousands of times.  Although you can do "SELECT *", it is rarely worth the few keystrokes it saves -- imagine what happens if a column is added and you fail to adjust all the queries that have shortcuts like that.  I recommend you simply accept that you need to do some extra typing.

Answer (score 0):

Dear if there is only option of updating table rows from other table , you must mention all the columns if they are hundreds or thousands in count.
If you want to insert rows from other table, then there is a simple way.
The best and optimized way will be that: Write a script or code whatever you are best at.
Put the columns in an array and make a query builder for this purpose. Then run / execute the query.
looking forward for further assistance